# Best way to filter if a field present in nested object in elasticsearch exists?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I have 1,000,000 contacts which are from different groups. For example

```
{"gps_id": [{"gid": "G1"},{"gid": "G2"}],"is_active": true,"contact": "c1"}
{"gps_id": [{"gid": "G2"}],"is_active": true,"contact": "c2"}
....
{"gps_id": [{"gid": "G1"},{"gid": "G2"}],"is_active": true,"contact": "c1000000"}
```

Consider G1 has 500,000 contacts, G2 has 1,000,000 contacts out of it 500,000 contacts which are already present in G1.

I want to filter above document object based on the condition,
"fetch unique contact from all respective group by group id".

I tried Elastic script query as below. But it doesn't work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
         "must" : {
                "script" : {
                     "script" : {
                        "inline": "for (int i = 0; i < params.gps_id.length; ++i) {ctx._source.gps_id.add(params.gps_id[i]) }",
                        "lang": "painless",
                        "params": {
                            "gps_id": [
                              {
                                "gid": "G1"
                              },
                              {
                                "gid": "G2"
                              }
                            ]
                    }
                }
                }
            },
      "must": [

        {
          "match": {
            "is_active": true
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "gps_id",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "gps_id.gid": "G1"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here Group and its contact may increase in size.

Please suggest best way to implement it using Elasticsearch -5.1.2

Comment: Lakh as in 100.000 ? Do you have 100.000 * 10 = 1 million records to sort through? As this will influence how 'fast' the solution has to be.

Comment: @shilly yeah,kindky suggest a best way to get filtered result like loop the groups and filter based on  some logic etc